# UNIX Folder Recovery - edit

Tags: data-recovery

Has anyone had any luck with recovering a subdirectory with data?  We're talking about around 100MB and a specific folder name and location.  As I said in a previous post, I had a data folder in MySQL that has simply disappeared.  Although there has been one reboot, nothing new has been written to the server, so I'm thinking in theory it might still be there.

If you have any suggestions on how to do this or people that could help (who aren't cost prohibitive), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't have a backup to restore from you're probably just screwed. Beyond that, it would likely involve sending the HDD's to a data recovery company to see if they can find the data files still on disk (if those areas of disk haven't already been written to, I mean).

Comment: I think that more important than that is that you tell us the filesystem is it using and if you have physical access to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility to recover file hardly depends on filesystem. Some filesystems have recovery options and others (most) are very limited. For `ext3/ext4` (most used filesystems) there is [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).

Though, even success recovery of `mysql` directory cannot guarantee consistency of recovered database. It can be consistent only if data files were flushed by MySQL to disk during shutdown.

For success recovery make sure that the partition is read-only, the more data is written there since deletion, the less are chances to restore anything.